# Separating SQL row data into multiple textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, delimiter

I'm trying to load a SQL row of numbers into multiple text boxes. Basically the row contains numbers separated by ";".  How can I get it so that each number when separated by ";" is in their own textbox?

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAURA-PC;Initial Catalog=Sudoku;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select puzzle from Puzzle";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            textBox2?
            textbox3?
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: If possible, I suggest you make it a stored procedure instead of `CommandType.Text`.  You never want to keep the SQL directly in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the same amount of (or fewer) numbers than TextBoxes , you could put your TextBoxes into an array and use the following code:

```
...
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    string[] tokens = reader.GetString(0).Split(';');
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
    {
        textBoxes[i].Text = tokens[i];
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `puzzle` column has the semi-colon delimited numbers:

```
...
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    string[] tokens = ((string)reader[0]).Split(';');

    textBox1.Text = tokens[0];
    textBox2.Text = tokens[1];
    // etc...
}
...
```